# How to use Symfony get/setAttribute on nested Session Attributes?

Tags: php, json, symfony-1.4

I have a sfuser/attributes looking like this:

```json
session:
 symfony/user/sfUser/attributes: {
    symfony/user/sfUser/attributes:{
        15:{
            Telefon:'+304994994994',
            option:'15',
            rules:'12',
            arrayBunch:[{
              this: 'da',
              that: "where"
            }]
        },
        17:{...},
        mysetting: "val"
    },
    sfGuardSecurityUser:{},
    admin_module:{},
    sfGuardUserSwitcher:{}
}}
```

When i use **setAttribute("mysetting", "val")** they stores mysetting like show on my example. It is therefore unnecessary to use **setAttribute("mysetting", "val", 15)** because i got the same answer.

How can i access the nodes **15** or **arrayBunch** an use **setAttribute** to input a value there or **getAttribute** to get'em?

Comment: Are you sure about `setAttributes`? Because sfUser doesn't have `setAttributes` but has a `setAttribute`.

Comment: Sorry you are right! it's `setAttribute` i edit my post!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>I think you are doing it in a wrong way (about parameters).</s>

What you want to do is:

- add a variable called `val`
- with the value `15`
- in the namespace `mysetting`.

But, you have written parameters in a wrong order.

If you check [the code](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/user/sfUser.class.php#L274), parameters are :

```
public function setAttribute($name, $value, $ns = null)
```

So you should try:

```
->setAttribute('val', 15, 'mysetting');
```

**Edit:** *(sorry didn't notice the `arrayBunch` problem)*

If you want to edit the arrayBunch value:

```
// retrieve the current value
$arrayBunch = $this->getUser()->getAttribute("arrayBunch", array(), 15);

// made some modification
$arrayBunch['toto'] = 'titi';
$arrayBunch['this'] = 'do';

// put back the modification
$this->getUser()->setAttribute("arrayBunch", $arrayBunch, 15);
```

**Edit**:

With a closer look to your json, you should retrieve the whole attribute `15`, since the namepsace is [the default one](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/user/sfUser.class.php#L24): `symfony/user/sfUser/attributes`. So:

```
$attribute15 = $this->getUser()->getAttribute(15);
$arrayBunch  = $attribute15['arrayBunch'];
```

And if you want to apply some changes:

```
// update arrayBunch
$arrayBunch['this'] = 'dada';
// do not forget to re-add modified arraybBunch to the whole variable
$attribute15['arrayBunch'] = $arrayBunch

// and if you want to add a value
$attribute15['mysetting'] = 'val';

// then, save every thing to the session again
$this->getUser()->setAttribute(15, $attribute15);
```

Comment: in my example "15" is a namespace right? can i set a new value to this namespace with your example?

Comment: Well, you cannot assign a value to a namespace. You can assign variable which containt a value: `->setAttribute('my_variable', 'my_value', 'mysetting');`

Comment: There is no way to insert a new `'my_variable': 'my_value'` after `'array_bunch'` into `15` ??

Comment: `'array_bunch'` is just a variable name!

Comment: i've updated my post too! by the way `$arrayBunch = $this->getUser()->getAttribute("arrayBunch", array(), 15);` dont really work.

Comment: Hmm, how do you set the `17`, and `15` in the session?

Comment: Oh i got it!! :) To retrieve: `$arrayBunch = sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getAttribute(15);;` and then `$arrayBunch['arrayBunch'];` to get the array. I have not Test to made modification... can u update ur Post with that? so i can mark yours as an Answer? ;)

Comment: That's what I was just thinking about :)

Comment: To Set is really buggy!! i tried : `sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->setAttribute` or `$this->getUser()->setAttribute` with value: `setAttribute("valName", "val", 15)`.... but this never access the `session:
 symfony/user/sfUser/attributes: {
    symfony/user/sfUser/attributes:{`

Comment: How do you `var_dump` your session (like you did in your question) ? Because I don't understand why you have two `symfony/user/sfUser/attributes`.

Comment: it's maybe cause i used the plugin ('sfGuardUserSwitcher')?

Comment: Hum nop, don't think so. Still wanted to know how do you get your json?

Comment: There are shown so in `dev modus` under `config=>globals`. Into `config=>user` i see just one `sfUser/attributes` but my `setAttribute("valName", "val", 15)` add another namespace `15`... really dont understand.

Comment: amazing! it's works but i see the changes into `config=>globals` but not into `config=>user` so that in Template `var_dump($sf_user->getAttribute(15));` i cant see the changes... how that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15123/discussion-between-j0k-and-trouble)